# Cloud computing service for PHP and Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, cloud, saas, paas

I am using `PagodaBox` to scale `PHP` applications deployed via `git`.
In this application I would like to include also `Node.js`.
To me, PagodaBox seems not able to integrate Node.js. Can you recommend me another `IaaS`, `PaaS` or `SaaS` service?

Answer (score 2):

dotCloud and OpenShift (by Red Hat) supports both Node.js and PHP. Unsure of wether you can combine them into one instance though.

Comment: On OpenShift you can't combine them.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure supports node.js and PHP, along with git deployment:

[Azure Web Sites](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/web-sites/)

[Node Developer Center](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/)

[PHP Developer Center](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/)

Comment: It's unbelievable how good Windows Azure is. Damn it, WTF has happended to Microsoft ?

Comment: But, maybe a little bit offtopic: In Europe people don't really use/have credit cards, so Azure really needs other payment methods. It's a strange situation when you want to buy things but have no technical possibily to do so...